# What is the run-time complexity of this Code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory, analysis

What is the run-time complexity of this Code?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
    int n, i, l, j, c, ans = 25;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char x[21], y[21];
    scanf("%s", &x);
    l = strlen(x);
    for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", &y);
        c = 0;
        for(j=0 ;j<l; j++)
            if(x[j] == y[j])
                c++;
            else
                break;
        strcpy(x, y);
        if(ans > c)
            ans = c;
    }
    printf("%d", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

My lecturer tells me that the complexity of this code is `O(n*n)` but I'm not convince with this answer cause the inner loop runs string length times.

Comment: I don't get why you were down voted. You offer your own insight... I don't get this website anymore

Comment: I don't know, but you are a good man cause you noticed that :)

Comment: Looks O(n * m) to me. Are you sure he said n*n? I would expect a professor to call that n^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime of `main()` is composed of the runtime of some constant-time statements and the runtime of the `i`-loop:

```
T_main(n, l) ∈ O(1) + T_fori(n, l)
```

The `i`-loop runs exactly `(n - 1)` times and is composed of some constant-time statements and the runtime of the `j`-loop:

```
T_fori(n, l) ∈ (n - 1) * (O(1) + T_forj(n, l))
```

The runtime of the j-loop depends on the data. In the best case, the first character of `x` and `y` are different, thus:

```
T_forj_best(n, l) ∈ 1 * O(1)
```

In the worst case, `x` and `y` have `l` equal first characters, thus:

```
T_forj_worst(n, l) ∈ l * O(1) = O(l)
```

This yields:

```
T_fori_best(n, l)  ∈ (n - 1) * (O(1) + O(1)) = O(n)
T_fori_worst(n, l) ∈ (n - 1) * (O(1) + O(l)) = O(n * l)
```

and

```
T_main_best(n, l)  ∈ O(1) + O(n)     = O(n)
T_main_worst(n, l) ∈ O(1) + O(n * l) = O(n * l)
```

Comment: Wouldn't your worst case be that the two strings (x and y) are equal up to length L? Not that the first characters are?

Comment: @Taekahn Yes, that's what I meant by "they have `l` equal first characters", meaning "their first `l` characters are equal".

Comment: sorry, that looks like a 1, not an L. :)